# Initializing 2 dimensional array and displaying them

Tags: java

I am trying to display and initialize my 2-d array through a loop. However, eclipse gives me an error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at lastassignment2.ModifyCar.main(ModifyCar.java:75)"

This is my code:
   package lastassignment2;

```
class Car {

private String brand;
private long serialNumber;
private double Price;

public Car (String br, long sN, double Pr)
{
    brand= br;
    serialNumber = sN;
    Price = Pr;
}
 public Car (Car aCar)
  {
    this(aCar.getbrand(), aCar.getserialNumber(), aCar.getPrice());
   }
 public String getbrand()
 {
    return brand;
 }
 public long getserialNumber()
 {
     return serialNumber;
 }
 public double getPrice()
 {
   return Price;
 }
 public void setBrand(String carBrand)
  {

     //allows to set the brand of the carphone
    brand = carBrand;
}
public void setSerialNumber(long SN)
{
     // Sets the Serial Number of the car

    serialNumber = SN;
}
public void setPrice(double Pr)
{
     // Sets the price of the car

    Price = Pr;
}
public String toString()
{
    return this.brand + ", " + this.serialNumber + " " + this.Price;

}
public boolean equals(Car phone)
{
    if (Price == phone.Price  && brand.equals(phone))
        return true;
    else
        return false;}
public boolean equals2(Car phone)
{ if (Price == phone.Price)
    return true;
else
    return false; 
}
public boolean equals3(Car phone)
{ if (brand.equals(phone));
    return true;
}

}
 public class ModifyCar {
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {    
     Car[][] carArr  = new Car[10] [10];
     for (int i=0; i< CarArr.length-1; i++)
       { for (int m=0; m<carArr[m].length; m++)
          {  if (i % 3 == 0)
            carArr[i][m]= new Car("Samsung", 00000001 + (2 * i+1), 500.4 + i);
          else if (i % 3 == 1)
              carArr[i][m] = new Car("LG", 0000001 * (2 * i), 500.6 + i);
          }
     for (int y=9; y<carArr.length; y++)
        { for (int n=0; n<carrArr[y].length; n++)
             { 
               carArr[y][n] = new Car(carArr [y-7][n]); 
              }
         }

     for (int p = 0; p < carArr.length; p++) {

            // Loop and display sub-arrays.
            for (int x = 0; x < carArr[p].length; x++) {
            System.out.print(carfArr[p][x] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
       }


     }
    }
   }
```

I'm trying to initialize everything through for loop ( mainly for practice as I'm kinda weak with them)

The last 2 for loops were created in order to represent the array through a table format.

Comment: What is the unresolved compilation problem? There is part of that message missing.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with initializing 2-D array, it is simply misc syntax error which caused compilation problem....

Comment: well you see, I thought it might be the loop as far as I knew...  I really didn't know where to look because I used the car class in another program and it worked fine. So I thought maybe it could be the way  I typed out my loop to display the table style array

Answer (score 0):

Your main method had some compilation issue:

Below is the corrected code:

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {    
     Car[][] carArr  = new Car[10] [10];
     for (int i=0; i< carArr.length-1; i++)
       { for (int m=0; m<carArr[m].length; m++)
          {  if (i % 3 == 0)
            carArr[i][m]= new Car("Samsung", 00000001 + (2 * i+1), 500.4 + i);
          else if (i % 3 == 1)
              carArr[i][m] = new Car("LG", 0000001 * (2 * i), 500.6 + i);
          }
     for (int y=9; y<carArr.length; y++)
        { for (int n=0; n<carArr[y].length; n++)
             { 
               carArr[y][n] = new Car(carArr [y-7][n]); 
              }
         }

     for (int p = 0; p < carArr.length; p++) {

            // Loop and display sub-arrays.
            for (int x = 0; x < carArr[p].length; x++) {
            System.out.print(carArr[p][x] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
       }


     }
    }
```

Comment: Weirdly now I get the following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at lastassignment2.Car.<init>(ModifyCar.java:19)
 at lastassignment2.ModifyCar.main(ModifyCar.java:88)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use the eclipse IDE it'll help you with compilation problems like this. you have 3 spelling mistakes and the internal class can't be public:

1. remove public from line 70
2. CarArr to carArr line 74
3. carrArr to carArr line 82
4. carfArr to carArr line 92

Comment: I tried using the debugging option but I'm still " green " with eclipse. I'm really going in blind and doing my best :/

Comment: no worries, happy to help if you need more info. did the comments i made get you up and running or are you still having problems?